# What is the unit of measurement of Shapes.AddShape method in Microsoft Office Interop Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, shapes

I am trying to create shapes using

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape

For example,

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape rect = document.Shapes.AddShape((int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle,
    10, 10, 15, 15);
```

The second and third parameters say that my rectangle's top-left point is 10 points away from the top-left corner of the page. The fourth and fifth parameters specify 15 units of width and height to the rectangle.

I am precisely interested in knowing the **unit of measurement** used in each of the parameters mentioned above. This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff939462.aspx) from msdn did not help much as it says this measurement is in **points**. It would have been helpful if I got some clue in centi-meters or inches as I am printing these shapes in a MS Word document and shapes should scale to requirements in any of the units.

Any idea what these units are or how to convert points to any defined units (cm. or in.)? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Left, Top, Width, and Height arguments, numeric values are evaluated in points; strings can be in any units supported by Microsoft Publisher (for example, "2.5 in").

The Application class from the Word object model provides the following methods for converting one to another:

- [CentimetersToPoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838159(v=office.15).aspx) - converts a measurement from centimeters to points.
- [PointsToCentimeters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195052(v=office.15).aspx) - converts a measurement from points to centimeters (1 centimeter = 28.35 points).

You can read about [points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29) in Wikipedia.

Comment: It seems really odd, but using these conversion methods for large values does _not_ produce the correct result in my case. When setting the page width for example to CentimetersToPoints of 50 cm, indeed Word tells me that the page has 49,99 cm. Instead using a conversion factor of 1 mm = 2.834755 points (value found by experiments, may be a little different for even more precision) does the trick, producing 50 cm.